# Need to use dynamic variables to build the 'execute sp_executesql' parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a quick question about the use of execute sp_executesql

Without going into too much details of my code that's current causing an error, i'm more interested in the different methods I could use to build the EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL statement

Within my STOR_PROC, I have the following (with @tTableName & @tVar as parameters being passed in)

```
DECLARE @strSQL nVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @parmDef nVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @outDef nVARCHAR(100)

SET @strSQL = N'SELECT @nTotalOut = sum(r.TOT_SALES) FROM @tTableName
--this procedure is actually in a loop, as I need to provided total sales
--from multiple years and sales data per year is stored in its own individual table
--(ie: @tTableName = '2015_Sales_Data', '2014_Sales_Data', etc, etc)

SET @parmDef = N'@nTotalOut int output'
set @outDef = N'@nTotalOut=' + @tVar + ' OUTPUT'

execute sp_executesql @strSQL, @parmDef, @outDef
```

the reason why I need to dynamically define @outDef is because for each iteration, I need to store the total sales into its own variable (so @tVar will hold the actual variable names, ie: @nTotal2015, @nTotal2014, @nTotal2013, etc, etc)

At the end when this loop is done, I can do a

```
SELECT @nTotal2015, @nTotal2014, @nTotal2013
```

and display the total sales per year in 1 row

PROBLEM: 
when I run my store procedure, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

I've tried many different workarounds before I decided to post here, but at the end, I would like to know if i can build the EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL statement with dynamical variables

One thing to note: If i hardcoded the output parameter to:

```
execute sp_executesql @strSQL, @parmDef, @n2015Total=@n2015Total OUTPUT
```

then it works!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Run the code using a single variable and stash the value in a temporary table.

```
declare @Totals table (year int, total decimal(18, 6));

.  . .

execute sp_executesql @strSQL, @parmDef, @outDef;

insert into @Totals(year, total)
    select @year, @total;
```

This assumes that you have a `@year` variable among the variables being processed.

Comment: @year is definitely a variable i'm using

could you elaborate more on how '@year' and '@total' would be populated from your example?

also, how would you define '@outDef'?  using that variable for that parameter is what's causing an error

thx